# gathering two different data.frames with different amount of rows in R with cbind

Tags: r

I have two different data.frames, they are spectrums. The first one has 162 rows and the second one has 112 rows. Both of them has 4 columns.
The rows show the energy and the columns show the optical density.
Some energy points of the first spectrum with 162 rows has the same value as the second spectrum with 112.
Now I am trying to gather these both df's without merging. It should bound like `cbind()`.
The amount of 50 rows (162-112) can be delete or shown as NA.

---

**EDIT**

yes :) It works, thanks a lot! 
But is there an option to sort the df? 
If you look at the picture, you can see two red boxes each of them is a row of the df.

[image: picture]

The blue box shows the energy value which must be in the same row. Every energy value of spektrum4, which is not matching to the spektrum1, can be removed!
Is there an option of the package rowr?

Comment: Try `bind_cols` from the `dplyr` package.

Comment: why not try `join` left/right in this case??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Fill with NA

Here's a solution to fill NA's:

```r
library(rowr)
cbind.fill( df1, df2, fill=NA )
```

I see rowr has been removed. bummer.

You can get it in two ways:

- from the archive: https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/rowr/
- from github: https://github.com/cvarrichio/rowr

so...

```r
install.packages( "https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/rowr/rowr_1.1.3.tar.gz" )

# -OR-

devtools::install_github("cvarrichio/rowr")
```

### NA-fill without using rowr

Here's a fairly minimal solution that doesn't rely on rowr:

```r
library(dplyr)

nrow <- max( c(nrow(df1),nrow(df2)) )
ncol <- ncol(df1) + ncol(df2)

d <- as.data.frame( matrix( nrow=nrow, ncol=ncol ) ) %>%
    setnames( c(names(df1), names(df2)) )

Reduce(
    x=list(df1,df2), init=0,
    f=function(a,b){ d[ 1:nrow(b), a + 1:ncol(b) ] <<- b; a + ncol(b) }
)
```

## Delete rows

```r
min.rows <- min( c(nrow(df1), nrow(df2) ))
cbind( df1[1:min.rows,], df2[1:min.rows,] )
```